# Setter Function in my class not working with C++

Tags: c++, c++17

So I'm new to C++ and I made a simple program that stores a variable on a class, but the setter function I made never works. What is wrong with my code and why?

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include "ExampleClass.hpp"

void yourMom(std::string test1, std::string test2) {
    Test example{};

    int Integer1 = std::stoi(test1);
    int Integer2 = std::stoi(test2);

    example.setA(Integer1);
    example.setB(Integer2);
}

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 5;

    Test example{a, b};
    std::string operation{};
    char * string;
    string = "12 45";

    std::string str(string);
    int pos = str.find(" ");

    std::string a_str = str.substr(0, pos);
    std::string b_str = str.substr(pos + 1);

    std::cout << example.getA() << " " << example.getB() << "\n";

    yourMom(a_str, b_str);

    std::cout << example.getA() << " " << example.getB() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Cool function name

Comment: You have *two different and separate* variables named `example` in different scopes. The variable `example` in the `main` function is different from the variable `example` in the `yourMom` function. You might need to read more about variables, scope and life-time.

Comment: This has nothing to do with classes and everything to do with variable scope. Where you have written `yourMom(a_str, b_str);`, there is no reason to expect this to have any effect on the local variable `example` within the `main` function, because the `yourMom` function has no knowledge of that variable. You need to review fundamentals; if you are confused by something like this, then by studying classes you are trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: Oh right! I forgot the example variable is a different variable from the one in the main class. I'm sorry, I'm a beginner at C++.

Comment: *"I made a simple calculator program that gets input with a char, converts it to a std::string, then converts it to an int that is calculated. I then wanted to store the variable on a class where the calculating functions are, but the setter function I made never works."* -- this is way too much functionality for a [mre]. Please simplify to "a simple program that stores a variable on a class, but the setter function I made never works". Drop all functionality that is not needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I'll edit the question to add that.

Comment: Well, I changed the function to accept a Test variable and it works. Again, I'm new to C++ and I didn't even consider the variable that is containing a class itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that function name is nice ;) 
Second of all, no you cant do things like that in C++. Theres something called [`scope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/scope-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160#:%7E:text=When%20you%20declare%20a%20program,visible%20within%20that%20function%20body.)s in C++.

The `Test example{};` in the `yourMom` function is instantiated inside the scope of that function. Which means that the `Test example{a, b};` cannot be altered by the `Test example{}` which is inside the `yourMom` function.

How can I fix the issue? 
One option is to pass the `example` variable by reference. The function would look something like this,

```cpp
void yourMom(Test& example, std::string test1, std::string test2) {
    int Integer1 = std::stoi(test1);
    int Integer2 = std::stoi(test2);

    example.setA(Integer1);
    example.setB(Integer2);
}
```

This way when you assign something to `example` in `yourMom` function will be altered to the `example` variable in the `main` function.

The other way is by passing in the address of the variable. This would be that,

```cpp
void yourMom(Test* example, std::string test1, std::string test2) {
    int Integer1 = std::stoi(test1);
    int Integer2 = std::stoi(test2);

    example->setA(Integer1);
    example->setB(Integer2);
}

int main()
{
    ...

    yourMom(&example, a_str, b_str);

    ...
}
```

This means that the function can alter the very address which the `example` variable which is in the `main` function has.

Implement what suits you!

Bonus: There's another way to do this. Its a little advanced (depending on your level of knowledge). Try figuring it out, would be a fun exercise :). Hint: It has something to do with `return` and an operator overload.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly! I used the version where I passed the address of the variable.